# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, typescript

All code work good, but when I put `then` to the returned module all code crashes and throws error. Is the problem from that the export is function? If it is not from the function may someone explain why?

**This is the module**

```
export default {
  search: function(searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy) {
    fetch(
      `http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${searchTerm}&sort=${sortBy}&limit=${searchLimit}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data.data.children.map(data => data.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
};
```

**This is actual main JavaScript file**

```
import reddit from "./redditApi";

const searchForm = document.querySelector("#search-form");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

// form eventlistener
searchForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get search term
  const searchTerm = searchInput.value;
  // get sort
  const sortBy = document.querySelector('input[name="sortby"]:checked').value;
  // get limit
  const searchLimit = document.querySelector("#limit").value;
  // check input
  if (searchTerm === "") {
    // show message
    showMessage("Please add a search Term!", "alert-danger");
  }
  // clear input
  searchInput.value = "";
  // search reddit
  reddit.search(searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay! Can you share the error with us that has been thrown?

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>** This is the error

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a promise, but `search` doesn't have any `return` statement at all.

After you call `catch` on it, the promise is discarded.

If you want to use it outside the `search` function then you need to return it.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to do that

```
 reddit.search(searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy)
     .then(results => {
         console.log(results);
     })
     .catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
     });
```

you should wrap fetch inside a Promise.

example:

```
export default {
  search: (searchTerm, searchLimit, sortBy) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fetch(`http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${searchTerm}&sort=${sortBy}&limit=${searchLimit}`)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(data => resolve(data.data.children.map(data => data.data)))
              .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  }
};
```